# Image not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, camera

Image is not shown here. It was working two days ago but I made some changes and something went wrong. This is the code I placed inside the onPictureTaken (byte[] data , Camera camera) method of the jpeg Callback . The logcat displays the onPicture Taken Text but not the first two texts " callback recieved null data" and "bitmap not created"

Preview is a Linear Layout which both height and width match parent.

The output is showing a blank white screen.

```
    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            captureStatus = 1 ;
            Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (data == null) {
                        System.out.println("callback decieved null data");
                    }

                    mCamera = mPreview.stopCamera();
                    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, null);
                    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                    mat.postRotate(90);
                    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture, 0, 0, picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), mat, true) ;
                    pic = new ImageView(c);
                    pic.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                    preview.removeAllViews();
                    preview.addView(pic);
                    preview.requestLayout();
                    System.out.println("On picture taken");

                }
            };

        try {
            mPreview.yCamera.takePicture(null, null,rawCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: need to see the code above data ,, not after

Comment: Oops, the problem was something else. This code was correct. But the project was not building after making changes to the code and it was the same old APK when I had changed the code. It was because I tried to import some libraries and some settings were going wrong.

Not I made a new project and copied the code in it and din't import the libraries and the code is working fine.